# UPDATE: C++ undefined reference

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

When I try to run the following C++ program: **UPDATE** (Updated code since the past link had some errors): http://pastie.org/private/pdpfpzg5fk7iegnohebtq

I get the following:

[image]

**UPDATE**

The errors that arise now are as follows:

[image]

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some form of tabification to your code. It's painful to read right now. Also, you should be able to add just the GradeBook class definition and the lines that cause the linker error to this question, saving potential answerers from having to click a link just to get more information about the problem.

Comment: (1) Please post your code _here_.  Making it difficult for us to find and read your code is not helpful.  (2) Does copy and paste not work on your computer?  Is there a reason you've posted a screenshot?

Comment: @James McNellis. Just didn't think about pasting the screen shot on pastie while posting the question. Thanks.

Comment: see updated answer for the maximum issue

Comment: Like James McNellis said, please post code *here*.  If you're having trouble posting code, all you need to do is paste the code, highlight it, and hit the "code" button in the editor.  Also, whenever possible, please copy-and-paste error messages rather than pasting screenshots. Doing so  makes it more likely that other people that have the same error will find this page and be able to figure out their problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking in GradeBook.o so you're getting an undefefined reference.
Try

```
g++ GradeBookMain.cc GradeBook.cc -o GradeBookMain
```

You also have a typo "maximun" instead of "maximum" in GradeBook.h

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t tell your compiler where to find the `GradeBook` constructor definition (hence “undefined reference”). You need to pass all source files separately to the compiler, or create intermediate object files for all compilation units, and link them together.

Effectively, the easiest solution is this:

```
g++ GradeBookMain.cc GradeBook.cc -o GradeBookMain
```

Comment: When you say: "or create intermediate object files for all compilation units, and link them together.", how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

To quote one of my favorite IRC bots: Undefined reference is a linker error. It's not a compile error. #includes don't help. You did not define the thing in the error message, you forgot to link the file that defines it, you forgot to link to the library that defines it, or, if it's a static library, you have the wrong order on the linker command line. Check which one.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is case sensitive. So, for instance you can displayMessage, but what you define is DisplayMessage. Those are two distinct functions. You should change the definition of DisplayMessage to displayMessage, or when you call it call DisplayMessage not displayMessage

Answer (score 1):

What your compiler is telling you, is that the GradeBook class is defined and everything is OK at the compiling stage, but when the time comes to link a complete executable program, it can't find the actual code for that class. And this is because you have compiled and linked only GradeBookMain.cc and not GradeBook.cc. You can compile and link them both at the same time like this:

```
g++ GradeBookMain.cc GradeBook.cc -o program
```

Or you can compile them separately and then link together:

```
g++ -c GradeBookMain.cc -o GradeBookMain.o
g++ -c GradeBook.cc     -o GradeBook.o
g++ GradeBookMain.o GradeBook.o -o program
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also compile in GradeBook.cc.

At the moment the class itself is not being compiled or linked, and as such, the linker cannot find the GradeBook class - causing it to complain.